# why serialization in java, when i can copy class files to new JVM? both does same task right?

Tags: java, serialization, jvm

Do we need serialization to carry java objects across JVM when we can carry those by using class files itself.

Comment: First of all, do you understand the difference between Class and Object?. And secondly, what do you understand by Serialization?. have a look @aniket's answer...

Comment: Class: DesignForCar Object: myCar. With the class files I can create a new car. With a serialised MyCar I can recreate it exactly as it was. Travelling at 54.3mph with 100,015 miles on the clock and a slightly dented bonnet

Comment: You made it clear @Richard Tingle, i will never forget that "dented bonnet" ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got your concept wrong.

Serialization saves the state of the object converts into byte stream so that it can be transferred via network or saved in a persistent storage and then object can be reconstructed with same state. You cannot do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need serialization to carry java objects across JVM

Yes.

> when we can carry those by using class files itself.

No you can't. A class file isn't an object.